# Python parse packets real time

Tags: python, packet-capture

I want to collect bluetooth beacon info.
first of all,I need to collect all the network packets emmited by beacon in real time.
And than I have to parse the packets to get some value like `MAC address` ,  `RSSI`   and save into database.
I google for a while,but still have no idea how to design it
I only write a little `django` before.
But this seems not like a `web`

I find a package named `scapy`
But it's interactive shell , so I don't think it work under my demand

Please give me some advice.
What tools will you recommend??  What directions should I survey ?

Comment: what is your os platform?

Answer (score 0):

[Capture Incoming Bluetooth Packets with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579912/capture-incoming-bluetooth-packets-with-python)

check this question...

http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/ LightBlue: a cross-platform Python Bluetooth API